# Debian 12 Net Install Laptop no WiFi drivers, USB alternative, Upgrade Kernel, realtek b852 rtw89_8852be RTL8852BE 10ec:b852 17-cn3030TU

Tags: debian, wifi, laptop, debian-installer

So got this new laptop HP 17-cn3030TU and decided to not even boot into windows once, and only run Debian :)

Problem is the net install of Debian 12 doesnt detect the built in wifi chip (identifiers in the title)

Helpfully I found there is the option to open a shell command prompt from the installer so you can run commands like lspci and lsusb and dmesg to see what device you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried about 6 different usb wifi adapters I had lying around and there was one, the cheapest ebay one that actually was detected and worked !

This is what it looks like:

[image]

So now I was able to install the OS get it running, and research getting the on board wifi working.

Initially I found several github repos with likely compatible drivers that one could compile, but then i found some mention that newer kernel versions had the drivers in already ! So to be offered newer kernel in package manager you have to install debian backports sources

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports contrib non-free main
```

and then find the last linux-image package, in my case `linux-image-6.6.13+bpo-amd64`

And then my onboard wifi worked :)

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8852BE PCIe 802.11ax Wireless Network Controller [10ec:b852]
```